# Toggle Caps lock with command line batch file / RDP sync Caps lock

Tags: remote-desktop, batch-file, sync, capslock

Whilst working from home using RDP and having email auto correct constantly putting my Caps lock out of sync, I've been looking at ways that I can re-sync and pre-set the CAPS lock status when opening a new email or PDF form.
To open a PDF form and have Caps lock ON and re-synced, I have found the following code that works, which turns Caps lock off, if its on and then will toggle it back on again before opening the PDF file.
I would however like to simplify this to speed the process up.
Is there a better way to write this, maybe combine the first 2 lines onto one line?

Any suggestions please?
Thank you.

```
@echo off
start /b /wait powershell.exe -nologo -WindowStyle Hidden -sta -command "IF ([console]::CapsLock -eq 'True'){$wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;$wsh.SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')}" 
start /b /wait powershell.exe -nologo -WindowStyle Hidden -sta -command "$wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;$wsh.SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')"
start "" /wait /D"C:\Users\Claire\Desktop" "pdf-form.pdf"
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

The /B switch is of no real benefit here, and if the point is to simply ensure caps lock is on, you only need one line to enable it, using ne for not equal true.

```bat
    @start /wait powershell.exe -nologo -WindowStyle Hidden -sta -command "IF ([console]::CapsLock -ne 'True'){$wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;$wsh.SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')}"
    @start "" /wait /D"C:\Users\Claire\Desktop" "pdf-form.pdf"
    @exit /B 0
```

Comment: Thanks T3RR0R, the original point was to resync caps lock between remote and local when Outlook email auto capitalisation throws the sync out. Running the SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')} does actually resync the caps. Can the 2 lines be combined into one? Like SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')} and then again with the IF to set final state. The one line approach does insure caps lock is on but it doesn't run the SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')} to resync between remote and local if caps is already on. Not sure that would speed things up though? Thank you.